# FFMPEG split a video into multiple scenes/shot videos

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-editing, video-encoding, ffprobe

I want to use `FFMPEG` (or `ffprobe`) to split a video into multiple shot videos/scenes (`scene1.mp4` to `sceneX.mp4`, each a separate video). So whenever there is a scene change, it should cut it. What is the best command to do it?

So far I was using the following command (with `scenecut` option) but it is not perfect. Looks like there is [another option](https://superuser.com/questions/819573/split-up-a-video-using-ffmpeg-through-scene-detection) using `select=gt(scene\,.4)` (but it stores it into figures). So what is the right command with highest accuracy?

```
ffmpeg -i myVideo.mp4 -y -c:v libx264 -profile:v high -prese6t:v fast -deinterlace -x264opts min-keyint=15:keyint=1000:scenecut=20 -b:v 2000k -c:a aac -b:a 128k -f segment -segment_format mp4 -segment_format_options movflags=empty_moov+frag_keyframe+default_base_moof+skip_trailer+faststart /home/1/output%%05d.mp4
```